# Fast switch between three keyboard layouts - from Unity DE to Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, 15.10, keyboard-layout, gtk3

I use ubuntu 15.10 and have 3 keyboard languages layout. In Unity DE I create custom shortcuts:

```
key: CTRL+1; command: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 0

key: CTRL+2; command: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 1 

key: CTRL+3; command: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources current 2
```

With this shortcuts I can switch to first keyboard layout with CTRL+1,second with CTRL+2 and third with CTRL+3.
Now I try gnome-shell and this shortcuts not work on it. Can anybody help? 
Thank you for any advices.

Comment: No, it's impossible because gnome-shell has independent daemon for layout switch. It override all interactions with layout 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The solution for Gnome Shell.

Add custom hotkey with command.

***To switch to the first layout:***

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Eval "imports.ui.status.keyboard.getInputSourceManager().inputSources[0].activate()"
```

**inputSources[0]** - index of layout.

```
> inputSources[0] - first, 

> inputSources[1] - second.
```

etc.

[image]